# Валидация скрытого поля на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Как сделать чтобы работала валидация required для одного конкретного скрытого поля из массива полей для загрузки, например

```
        <input style="display:none" type="file" id="filename1" name="filename[]">
        <input style="display:none"  type="file" id="filename2" name="filename[]">
```

с помощью jquery validation? К этим полям в html странице прилагаются картинки-фреймы, в которых отображ. миниатюрные изображения. Нужно их провалидировать, чтобы они не были пустыми.

Comment: А, собственно, как и для чего должна отображаться валидация на скрытом поле?

Comment: К этим полям в html странице прилагаются  картинки-фреймы, в которых отображ. миниатюрные изображения. Нужно их провалидировать, чтобы они не были пустыми

Comment: Кем прилагаются?

Comment: Неважно, эти поля хоть и не видны, но должны быть заполнены файлами и, в случае если они пустые, нужно вывести сообщение валидации, что необходимо загрузить изображение.